# Possible to execute child process from Angular 2 to Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

On my site I have a front end of angular calling a back end of express.

Some of the express calls hit a database to execute stored procedures which can take a long time.

These long wait times for a response from Express to get back to angular cause a 504 error.

Is there anyway to set this up to where angular sends the execution message to Express and then the user continues to use the angular site while the long running stored procedure finishes on express? (Currently if the user executes one of these long running processes and then moves around the angular site it will kill the process).

Sample Angular Call:

```js
getDnSP(DnSPCall): Observable<DnSpResult[]> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:4200/'+'dn_sp';
  const data = ({
    dnspcall: DnSPCall
  });
  return this._http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <DnSpResult[]> res;
    })
  );
}
```

Sample Express:

```js
router.post('/dn_sp', function (req, res) {
  var dnspcall = req.body.dnspcall;
  console.log(dnspcall);
  var sql = "CALL " + db + ".DN_OBJECT(" + dnspcall + "P_ERROR_CD,P_MSG);";
  return db.read(sql)
    .then((x) => {
      console.log(x);
        };
        client.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No errors!");
      }
      console.log("Error Code: " + errorcd);
      res.send(x);
    })
});
```

Comment: You could use `websockets` like [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to push information to the client when request has been completely processed

Comment: You can send response from express to user and run store procedure in separate event.

Comment: @Bernhard -- the problem I having though is if the user changes the page and submits another query it will kill the original query.